# edgeguides code - confused about a particular error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ok ...

```
 <%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
   <% if @article.errors.any? %>
     <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:</h2>
     <ul>
       <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
       <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
     </ul>
  </div>
   <% end %>
   <p>
<%= f.label :title %><br>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

   <p>
<%= f.label :text %><br>
<%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Ok, code above is from http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Question pertains to this part:

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
   <% if @article.errors.any? %>
```

If I change `:article` to `@article` in first line, it still works. And it should, right because they're interchangeable, yes?

But if I change the second one like this:

`@article.errors.any?` to `:article.errors.any?`

it generates errors, specifically this:

`undefined method 'errors' for :article:Symbol`

Why??

Please do be gentle as I'm still trying to figure what may seems obvious to you.

Thinking out loud here, the reason why symbol doesn't work for second line is that it needs an instance of it to collect the errors, right?

But then, aren't symbols interchangeable with instances? Meaning that Rails should read that line and translate it into an instance, ie, it finds the instance of the model class, yes?

**EDIT**

apparently, I didn't read far enough again, and I didn't take to heart what I learned previously of form_for helper ...

EdgeGuides says this after the code:

`The first parameter of the form_tag can be an object, say, @article which would cause the   helper to fill in the form with the fields of the object. Passing in a symbol (:article) with the same name as the instance variable (@article) also automagically leads to the same behavior. This is what is happening here. More details can be found in form_for documentation.`

The key is form_for helper.

That's why it doesn't work for the second line ... because it cannot figure out how to fill in the place of the symbol.

Hopes this helps some other poor guys/gals.

ps. feel free to correct me if my edit is wrong.

Comment: Have you get answer of your questions are still have some doubts ?

Answer (score 0):

```
:article is only the model (not really sure :)
@article is an instance with data in it
   when Article.new empty, Article.find(..) with data
```

In my applications I use always

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
```

then I am sure that the form and the f variable reflects the instance @article
and all fields will be filled as expected.

In more complicated routes I use the url parameter as well.

```
<%= form_for :article, :url => articles_path do |f| %>
```

But it's only more clear if it goes in direction nested routes.

Answer (score 0):

Although form_for :article and form_for @article both work, but that only means that the form_for method can gather the needed information from either @article or :article. It doesn't mean symbols and instance is interchangeable.